Avro Schema Registration .NET
Is there a way to pass avro object through Kafka without using Schema Registration?
I've been looking online and all the example seems to force you to use schema registration, I want to find a way to do this without needing to register schema
ex:
var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig()
{
Url = "https://platform.local:24000/",

// Ssl settings, we use custom certificate authorities for 
Schema Registry as well
SslCaLocation = $"{RootFolder}/certificates/trustedCa.pem",
EnableSslCertificateVerification = false,

// Use the SASL Credentials
BasicAuthCredentialsSource = AuthCredentialsSource.SaslInherit
};


using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<GenericRecord, 
GenericRecord>(producerConfig)
 .SetKeySerializer(avroSerializer)
 .SetValueSerializer(avroSerializer)


You can send the Avro-serialized data or any byte array using the ProducerBuilder<Null, byte[]> type (see GitHub issue here). You can use for example AvroConvert to serialize your data and then produce it.
But it is also worth mentioning that Confluent Kafka C# libraries pushes you to use schema registry because it is the best practice, you can view and modify message schemas and even reject messages that are not following the correct schema. Without the schema registry, if the producer sends new data that are incompatible with the consumer, the consumer maybe will throw an exception.

Thanks for this . Where do we exactly register Schema , is this done inside of the application itself?

You can use the REST API or via the Confluent library, check this sample repo: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroBlogExamples/Program.cs

Avro is invented for schema compatibility issues and therefore you should use it to safeguard against schema violations happening from producers/consumers
The use of Schema Registry is required, you can't produce objects without Schema Registry.
When you write your objects serialized with json, Kafka automitcally creates the json schema for you.
But Avro behaves differently and requires slightly more effort.
You create your Avro schema first from schema registry, use AvroSerializer/Deserializer instead of JsonSerializer for the producer/consumer builders, and you implement ISpecificRecord for each object you intend to produce.
Attached is a typical Avro message to produce.
I hope this helps a little.

